# SQL Insert into a table FROM 2 unrelated tables and NOT Exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, not-exists

I'm able to run the next sql script once, to insert some rows using information from 2 unrelated tables :

```
INSERT INTO CompanyCarType (Name, CompanyId, LastModDateTime, LastModUserId)
    SELECT T.Name,  C.Id , GETDATE() LastModDateTime, C.LastModUserId
    FROM CarType T 
    CROSS JOIN Company C
```

But, I need to be able to run this script many times without inserting duplicates, or failing in my case, as the table won't allow duplicated `CompanyId` 
and `Name`.

So I tried to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, but as there are 2 tables in the `SELECT` statement, I can't use an alias to refer to it, and the syntax is incorrect.

```
INSERT INTO CompanyCarType (Name, CompanyId, LastModDateTime, LastModUserId)
    SELECT T.Name,  C.Id , GETDATE() LastModDateTime, C.LastModUserId
    FROM CarType T 
    CROSS JOIN Company C)  AS T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name
                      FROM CompanyCarType T2
                      WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name)
```

There are a lot of goof examples out there using one table on the SELECT clause, but none then with 2 or more tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of rownumber while doing insert and then add Company ID in the where not exists clause.

```
INSERT INTO CompanyCarType 
(Name, CompanyId, LastModDateTime, LastModUserId)
SELECT T.Name,  C.Id , GETDATE() LastModDateTime, C.LastModUserId, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.name, c.ID order by LastModDateTime) rownum 
FROM CarType T CROSS JOIN Company C)  as T1
WHERE t1.rownum = 1 and  NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name
                    FROM CompanyCarType T2
                   WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name and t2.CompanyId = t1.ID)
```